# Installing third component into quasar 1.x framework fail to mount

Tags: quasar-framework

I use a third component from https://github.com/mattmezza/vue-beautiful-chat/tree/master with Nuxt 2 and Vue 2 without problem.

Now I have a project in quasar 1.22 and vue 2. I am trying to install the mentioned component.

I have the next error:

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

found in

---> <BeautifulChat>
       <App> at src/components/ChatComponent.vue
         <IndexContatos> at src/pages/contatos/Index.vue
           <QPage>
             <QPageContainer>
               <QLayout>
                 <MainLayout> at src/layouts/MainLayout.vue
                   <App> at src/App.vue
                     <Root>
```

Here is what I did. I created a boot file as:

```
// beautifulChat.js
import Chat from 'vue-beautiful-chat'
export default ({ Vue }) => {
  Vue.component('beautiful-chat', Chat)
}
```

and I add it into quasar.conf boot session.

In my page I am using:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ChatComponent />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ChatComponent from 'src/components/ChatComponent.vue'
export default {
  name: 'IndexContatos',
  components: {
    ChatComponent,
  },
}
</script>
```

and the ChatComponent is:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <beautiful-chat
      :always-scroll-to-bottom="alwaysScrollToBottom"
      :close="closeChat"
      ....
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'ChatComponent',
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
      participants: [],
      titleImageUrl:
        'https://a.slack-edge.com/66f9/img/avatars-teams/ava_0001-34.png',
    }
    ....
  }
}
</script>
```